# Plotting a Complex Relationship

Tags: complex-analysis

I was asked this for my homework and can't find anything in the book or online to help me. We've been asked to plot $(z-5i)(z^*-5i)=4$ in the complex plane. The previous question had $(z-4)(z^*-5)=4$ and I could rearrange to get $(z-5)^2+y^2=4$, which is just a circle, but this new problem becomes $(z-5i)^2+y^2=4$ and I don't know what to do with the $i$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: expand the product and use $z+ z^* = 2 \operatorname{Re}(z)\,$, then:

$$
4 = (z-5i)(z^* - 5i) = z z^* -5i(z+z^*)-25 \;\;\iff\;\; |z|^2-10i\operatorname{Re}(z) = 29
$$

It follows that $\,\operatorname{Re}(z) = 0\,$ and $\,|z|^2=29\,$, so $\,z=\,\cdots$

---

[ *EDIT* ]  P.S. Guess you meant $(z-\color{red}{5})(z^*-5)=4\,$, and $(\color{red}{x}-5)^2+y^2=4\,$ in the following:

> previous question had $(z-\color{red}{4})(z^*-5)=4\,$, and I could rearrange to get $(\color{red}{z}-5)^2+y^2=4$

In that case the conclusion is correct, but it also follows more directly by simply noting that $4=(z-5)(z^*-5)=(z-5)(z-5)^*=|z-5|^2 \iff |z-5|=2\,$, so the locus of $z$ is the circle of radius $2$ centered at point $5+0i$ on the real axis.

Use the same idea on the offchance that the question you meant to ask was $(z-5i)(z^*\color{red}{+}5i)=4$.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It didn't occur to me to move the * - definitely more elegant. And right I forgot the relation just means imaginary parts can't contribute. Guess I was stuck thinking of it as more of a complex function.